# How do I acquire the most recent SELECT action performed for an object in each schema in an Oracle database?

Tags: oracle, schema, usage-statistics

I am not an Oracle expert but have been tasked with retiring a popular Oracle database in a company, but doing so schema by schema. In order to do so I first need to determine when each schema was last accessed.  I used the following SQL to list all of the schemas. Can somebody provide help in listing the most recent access (using SELECT call action) date for each schema?

```
SELECT USERNAME FROM SYS.ALL_USERS
```

My research has only returned something similar but for each table.  I need the results to be specific to the schema level. Lastly, I am using Toad for Oracle.  Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select parsing_schema_name, min(first_load_time), to_char(max(last_active_time), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI')   from v$sql
group by parsing_schema_name
order by parsing_schema_name, max(last_active_time)
```

Output for example.

```
ALEXS           2018-04-18/10:10:34 2019-04-19 10:14
ASOUP           2018-04-18/10:10:04 2019-04-19 10:14
BEV257          2018-04-18/10:12:19 2019-04-19 10:14
BLACKBOX88      2018-04-18/10:09:42 2019-04-19 10:14
BLACKBOX_ASPT   2018-04-19/05:01:50 2019-04-19 05:02
BLACKBOX_ASUSPS 2018-12-20/11:32:42 2019-04-19 08:55
BLACKBOX_COUB   2018-04-18/10:12:39 2019-04-19 10:14
BLACKBOX_ETD    2018-04-18/14:00:42 2019-04-19 04:38
BLACKBOX_KASAT  2018-04-18/10:26:49 2019-04-19 10:06
BLACKBOX_NBD2   2018-04-19/00:30:55 2019-04-19 00:30
BLACKBOX_READ   2018-04-19/03:00:00 2019-04-19 03:36
BLACKBOX_WEB    2018-04-18/10:10:34 2019-04-19 10:14
BUGMK           2018-04-18/13:19:40 2019-04-19 10:14
```

Comment: Thanks!  That's exactly what I was seeking.